# Trap Ctrl+C in script

Tags: bash, suspend, systemd, ubuntu-mate

I have this just about the way I would like it.

But I can figure out how to trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so that if I want to end the script early, it can re-enable the suspend and hibernation modes.

I looked at other discussions of trapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but found none that were of help.

Thanks.

```
#     TimerInTerminal.sh

# To prevent your Linux system from suspending or going into hibernation, you need to disable the following systemd targets:
# sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

# To re-enable the suspend and hibernation modes, run the command:
# sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

soundfile="/usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Electronic_Chime.wav"
# Stop computer from sleeping while timer is running

# prevent your Linux system from suspending or going into hibernation
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

# This allows supend ?
#trap "echo marlin | sudo -S systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target" INT EXIT

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    DURATION="$1"
else
    read -r -p "Timer for how many minutes?( for fractional, use decimal notation , 0.5==30s, 1.25==75s etc) : "  DURATION
    read -r -p "Enter text to display at the end of the timer : " n1
fi

DURATION=$(echo "$DURATION * 60 / 1" | bc) # lets us deal with fractional inputs

START=$(date +%s)   # only do this once (anchor's the time)

countdown () {
    NOW=$(date +%s)              # Get time now in seconds
    DIF=$((NOW - START))         # Compute diff in seconds
    ELAPSE=$((DURATION - DIF))   # Compute elapsed time in seconds
    MINS=$((ELAPSE / 60))        # Convert to minutes... (dumps remainder from division)
    SECS=$((ELAPSE - (MINS*60))) # ... and seconds
    #banner "$MINS:$SECS"
    echo "$MINS:$SECS"
    sleep "$1"
}

while true 
do
    clear
    
    countdown 0 # calc time remaining
    
    if [ $MINS -le 0 ]
    then
        # Blink screen

        while [ $SECS -gt 0 ]
        do
            
            clear # Flash on
            #setterm -term linux -back red -fore white 
            countdown 0.5

            clear # Flash off
            #setterm -term linux -default
            countdown 0.5

        done # End for loop
        
        setterm -term linux -default
        clear
        
        break   # time has expired lets get out of here
    
    else
        countdown 1 
    fi
done

echo $n1
amixer -D pulse sset Master 30% > /dev/null 2>&1
# Play a sound
cvlc --play-and-exit "$soundfile" > /dev/null 2>&1

# To re-enable the suspend and hibernation modes, run the command:
 echo marlin | sudo -S systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

This works. I will not insert my entire code in ctrl_c and see what happens.

```
 #!/bin/bash
    # trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
    trap ctrl_c INT
    
    function ctrl_c() {
            echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
    echo System will now have suspension/hibernation halted.
    
    # prevent your Linux system from suspending or going into hibernation
    sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
    sleep 10
}
ctrl_c
```

Comment: Shell scripting questions are perfectly on topic https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic. Hope that negative votes are not related to this being a bash programming question.

Comment: @Lorenz Keel I made a post at meta.askubuntu.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?  https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash

Comment: @Ray I agree with you 100 percent.

Comment: @Terrance I have that script but can not incorporate it into my script.

Comment: @LorenzKeel No, I'd say the same thing regardless of the language used.  And it isn't a matter of what the "rules" say; like I said, it's also about reaching a "wider" audience because someone using CentOS could answer that question just as well.  My comment is for the OP (to help him/her), but you just don't see it that way.  It's ok.

Comment: @fixit7 You would incorporate near the top of your script, but don't include the `for i.....` part of it.  You would need only the `trap ctrl_c INT` line and the function part added right below that line.  You would add whatever it is that you needed to the `ctrl-c` function.

Comment: @fixit7 You would add your last line of the `echo marlin....` into the `ctrl-c` function.

Comment: @Terrance I will add your recommendations and add to my orig posting what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can trap the `CTRL+C` in the script.  You don't call the `ctrl_c` function as that will be called when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the keyboard.  I added in an `exit 0` so that it exits the script after it traps the `CTRL+C` and stops looping through the `for .. loop`.

```
cat ctrl_test.bsh 
#!/bin/bash

#Setup trap command, assign what to call and what is the trigger (SIGINT)
trap ctrl_c INT

#Function of what trap command calls    
function ctrl_c() {
    printf "\n** Trapped CTRL-C after $i seconds.\n"
    exit 0
}

#Rest of script to print counting numbers to screen will not break with CTRL+C due to trap
for ((i=1;i>0;i++))
do
    printf "\r$i"
    sleep 1
done
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./ctrl_test.bsh 
13^C
** Trapped CTRL-C after 13 seconds.
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$
```

In your script case you could do something like this:

```
#TimerInTerminal.sh

#Trap Ctrl+C and re-enable suspend and hibernation modes
trap ctrl_c INT
function ctrl_c() {
    sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
    exit 0
}

# To prevent your Linux system from suspending or going into hibernation, you need to disable the following systemd targets:
# sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

# To re-enable the suspend and hibernation modes, run the command:
# sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

soundfile="/usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Electronic_Chime.wav"
# Stop computer from sleeping while timer is running

# prevent your Linux system from suspending or going into hibernation
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

# This allows supend ?
#trap "echo marlin | sudo -S systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target" INT EXIT

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    DURATION="$1"
else
    read -r -p "Timer for how many minutes?( for fractional, use decimal notation , 0.5==30s, 1.25==75s etc) : "  DURATION
    read -r -p "Enter text to display at the end of the timer : " n1
fi

DURATION=$(echo "$DURATION * 60 / 1" | bc) # lets us deal with fractional inputs

START=$(date +%s)   # only do this once (anchor's the time)

countdown () {
    NOW=$(date +%s)              # Get time now in seconds
    DIF=$((NOW - START))         # Compute diff in seconds
    ELAPSE=$((DURATION - DIF))   # Compute elapsed time in seconds
    MINS=$((ELAPSE / 60))        # Convert to minutes... (dumps remainder from division)
    SECS=$((ELAPSE - (MINS*60))) # ... and seconds
    #banner "$MINS:$SECS"
    echo "$MINS:$SECS"
    sleep "$1"
}

while true 
do
    clear
    
    countdown 0 # calc time remaining
    
    if [ $MINS -le 0 ]
    then
        # Blink screen

        while [ $SECS -gt 0 ]
        do
            
            clear # Flash on
            #setterm -term linux -back red -fore white 
            countdown 0.5

            clear # Flash off
            #setterm -term linux -default
            countdown 0.5

        done # End for loop
        
        setterm -term linux -default
        clear
        
        break   # time has expired lets get out of here
    
    else
        countdown 1 
    fi
done

echo $n1
amixer -D pulse sset Master 30% > /dev/null 2>&1
# Play a sound
cvlc --play-and-exit "$soundfile" > /dev/null 2>&1

# To re-enable the suspend and hibernation modes, run the command:
 echo marlin | sudo -S systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: Thanks, almost to Create tag synonyms. @Terrance

Comment: @fixit7 You're welcome!  I am glad I could help!  :-)